# reactjs application deployed to heroku can find any page other than start page

Tags: reactjs, heroku

I have a reactJS application which I finally got deployed on heroku.  When I test the application on my local development machine (and I have the correct "start" string in my package.json file, I get the initial page to display.  When I click on the 3 bars to open the menu and click on one of the menu items, I can see in the console (I am using Chrome) that the page loads and it does get displayed.  When I start the application, I see an entry in the log that states

```
Navigated to http://localhost:8080/
```

When I click on the 3 menu bars and select the "enter new property" menu option, I see this in the log

```
Navigated to http://localhost:8080/enterproperty
```

and the browser then displays the page.  This works as I expected.

I then changed the "start" script in package.json to contain this:

```
"dev-server": "webpack-dev-server --open",
"start": "node server.js",
"build": "webpack -p",
"heroku-postbuild": "npm run build"
```

and I executed the following git hub commands:

```
git add .
git commit -m "commitXX"
git push heroku master
git heroku
```

This launches my browser and opens up https://aqueous-shore-94052.herokuapp.com/ and my page opens.  When I look in the console.log, I see this:

```
Navigated to https://aqueous-shore-94052.herokuapp.com/
```

I clicked on the menu bars and selected enter new property and I see this in the console.log:

```
https://aqueous-shore-94052.herokuapp.com/enterproperty 404 (Not Found)
```

This is the contents of my server.js file:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const path = require('path')
const port = process.env.PORT || 3001

app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))

app.listen(port, () => console.log("Listening on Port", port))
```

Why would my screens not be found?

Comment: Can you share what's in your server.js file?

Comment: @Joao I updated my post to include the contents of the server.js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need a catch all middleware. Try adding this below the `express.static` line:

```
/*
Send request to the app, let it deal with 404s, etc
 */
app.use((req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html')
})
```

This says "If none of the above routes match, respond with this file" - this way your react app and `react-router` can do it's thing.

Comment: That did it.  Awesome!  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Is there a github repo you could direct us to? I would guess it has something to do with the routing on the front-end, albeit I can't say for sure.